# Last id's that were inserted to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am interested if I can get the ids for the most recently inserted data rows. I have a form that users can fill out and they can clone the form, so they can add 10 forms if they want... I just need all the id's that were inserted. So is this possible ?

Comment: Before the SQL that inserts the data, just store the ids into an array.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan I assume the ids are created by the insertion (via AUTO_INCREMENT column attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `mysql_affected_rows` mysql function to find the last affected row. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) is the documentation.

```
SET @uids := null;
UPDATE footable
   SET foo = 'bar'
 WHERE fooid > 5
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) );
SELECT @uids;
```

This will return a string with all the IDs concatenated by a colon.

Comment: You're welcome and don't forget to upvote and mark this as answer if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM [yourTable] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: It will give wrong results as soon as 2 different users insert records at the same time in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Too trivial with SQL's `ORDER-BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: It will give wrong results as soon as 2 different users insert records at the same time in the table.

Comment: @Jocelyn: How? That because of same id for two users?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in the simple sense; but you can change your logic to do the inserts one at a time if you need those ids.

Alternatively, you could do an approximation (with a level of reasonability that depends on your app) but selecting the MAX(id) before the insert, and then doing a `select ... WHERE id > $prev_max AND name IN (implode(',', $names))` (assuming there is some field such as name that you can use like this.

You can verify the validity of the selected rows by ensuring that the count is the same as the number of inserted rows. With two-factor (id > prev *and* something like the name column) it is extremely unlikely that you will get someone else's inserts when you select like this.

You could also consider attributing the rows to the user, which would eliminate any possibility of data collision, and then the method is really quite simple:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_id = $userID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $qtyForms;
```

Of course, decisions like this depend on how your app is structured.

Answer (score 0):

As AndreiCristianProdan stated in the comment: auto increment the IDs. Then something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 1 ORDER BY ID DESC
```

No two rows will ever be effected at -exactly- the same time. This will always select the -last- row in the table.

If you want -only- the rows effected by the one user, add a `user_id` field to the table. Then add

```
WHERE `user_id` = 'UserIdHere'
```

to the SQL statement.

Hope that helps.